# ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation in ReviewsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, error-handling, schema

Receiving this error in Rails:
PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column "reviewer_id" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (26, 2222, 2222, 8, null, 2021-01-30 19:26:03.354983, 2021-01-30 19:26:03.354983).

This app is trying to allow users to give other users reviews.
I am new, so the error may be quite obvious, but not to the untrained eye. After hours of research, this was my last resort.
I'd appreciate in help fixing this. God bless.

`routes.rb`

```
resources :users do
    resources :reviews, only: [ :new, :create ]
  end
```

`reviews_controller.rb`

```
 def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.user_id = current_user.id

    if @review.save
      redirect_to user_path(current_user), notice: 'Review added!'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def review_params
    params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :content)
  end
```

`schema.rb`

```
create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.integer "rating"
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.bigint "reviewer_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["reviewer_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_reviewer_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "username"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "offers", "games"
  add_foreign_key "offers", "users"
  add_foreign_key "rentals", "offers"
  add_foreign_key "rentals", "users"
  add_foreign_key "reviews", "users"
  add_foreign_key "reviews", "users", column: "reviewer_id"
```

`user.rb`

```
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :given_reviews, source: :reviews, foreign_key: :reviewer_id
  has_many :received_reviews, source: :reviews, foreign_key: :user_id
```

`review.rb`

```
  belongs_to :user
  validates :content, presence: true
  validates :rating, presence: true
```

Comment: Where are you setting `reviewer_id`?  The only two parameters you are allowing for reviews are rating and content.

Comment: Sounds like you want to do `@review.reviewer = current_user`. Do you have a `user` and a `reviewer` on purpose? aren't they the same?

Answer (score 1):

You have a database constraint on Review, for the reviewer_id field, defined in your schema here:

`t.bigint "reviewer_id", null: false`

In your `controller#create` action you are defining a `user_id`, but I don't see where you are passing in the `reviewer_id` or setting it.  If you have a field in the form, you'll need to add that param to the `review_params` so it can be passed from the form to the controller action.  Or you'll need to define it in the `create` action similar to how you've defined the `user_id`.

Since your reviewer is the person leaving the review, and the User is being reviewed, I would do this:

In your view where you are leaving the review, (I assume this would be `User#show`) you are viewing a specific user. You know which user this is and most likely in that view it is defined as `@user`, so you can most likely use `<%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, @user.id %>` in the form for the review. This will pass `user_id` to the Reviews#create action in the params.  You will also need to add `user_id` to `review_params` so it can be accessed in the `#create` action.

Then in your `Reviews#create` action, assign `@review.reviewer_id = current_user.id`.  `@review.user_id` will be assigned when you call `Review.create(review_params)` assuming you have added it the the form and the `review_params` as suggested above.

Try adding a breakpoint in the `create` action and look at the params object getting sent from the review form, this may be helpful for you to understand what's happening.

Typical Rails practice is to use a model validation as well. This way you'd get an app error before the request ever hits the database.

Comment: Thank you. I want a reviewer_id because the review will show the rating, the content, and who left the review. So, I would add "validates :reviewer_id, presence: true" to the review.rb, Then in the review contronller, :reviewer_id to the review_params. Then in the def create...
review instance = Review.new(review_params), review.user_id instance = current_user.id,  review.reviewer_id instance = current_user.id, and user instance = user.find(params[:user_id])?

Comment: So the `user_id` is for the person being reviewed, and the `reviewer_id` is for the person leaving the review?  If the reviewer is the person leaving the review, they are most likely the `current_user`, and you've already figured out how to assign that `id` to an attribute on Review.

Since you are leaving the review on a User, you will have access to that User's id in the view where you are leaving the review.  So you'd want to pass that id in with the params to the create action. You'll need to add `:user_id` to `:review_params`, and add a `hidden_field_tag` with `@user.id` in the view.

Comment: I edited my answer to be more specific and clear.

Comment: Did my answer help?